# Programming language to use in rpi 3

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio, sensor, windows-iot

I am trying to build a home intruder system where i will be using thermal image sensor to get the image of the creatures living around. Now which programming language should I use....Python, nodejs. Actually a newbie so don't have much idea. Any suggestions will really be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the old adage says the best programming language is the one you already know. If you are new to the Pi and to programming I would suggest Python, not because it is better than the rest, but simply because there are far more examples using Python available that will help you learn and make your project easier to complete.

Comment: I wouldn't use nodejs, because I cannot see any advantages to that.  If you're starting from nothing, Python would probably get you up more quickly because there are more examples in that language (sadly), but it may limit you down the road.  C/C++ would have a stepper learning curve but would allow more control at a lower level should you need it.  Java could also be ok. It has a relatively friendly threading model that may be handy, and there are a few open source packages for that.

Comment: To point out the elephant in the room, for Windows IoT the best would be using C# and the Universal Application SDK - Python, Java, C# syntax is similar enough if you wanted to switch between them and are all highly abstracted programming languages, to make it easier to use than C++ - Universal App has an easy to build UI using XAML that is directX driven, probably one advantage over python and java it is extremely easy to make the UI in Universal Apps